# Bootstrap grid system doesn't work on tables

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a settings for my WordPress plugin, I want my image to be displayed aside the table on the right, but it always goes to bottom can you guys help me to fix that ?

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">');
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label for="">test</label></th>
            <td>
                <input  name="x'.$key.'" value="'.$option['x'.$key].'" width="50px">
                 <button type="button" onclick="position('.$key.')" class="button button-primary">Create/Edit</button>
                <p class="description" id="">some discription</p>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label for="">test</label></th>
            <td>
                <input  name="myinput" value="'.$option['x'.$key].'" width="50px">
                 <button type="button" onclick="position('.$key.')" class="button button-primary">Create/Edit</button>
                <p class="description" id="">some discription</p>
            </td>
            </tr>
            ....
        </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="special">
        <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

// outputs the WP submit button html
//@submit_button();
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle showing the problem? Are you sure you're viewing on a medium or higher display?

Comment: We'd need to see the full code on a codepen or similar. But, seeing the actual page in question would be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a div element with "container" or "container-fluid" class after form element( `<form action="options.php" method="post">` )

like :`<form action="options.php" method="post"><div class="container">
...............
</div></form>`

OR

like :`<form action="options.php" method="post"><div class="container-fluid">
...............
</div></form>`